# Shouldn't using spread syntax not reference the original array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Object array in my state called `names`, i'm trying to make a copy of this array to another Object array in state called `shuffledNames`, but when i shuffle the `shuffledNames` using the code below, the original `names` changes the ids to match the new shuffled ids. See images below for an example. I've tryed using .concat(), .slice(). I do not know what to try anymore.

```
handleSort = () => {
  let tempName = [...this.state.names];

  let shuffledNames = tempName;

  for (let i = shuffledNames.length; i-- > 1; ) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    let temp = shuffledNames[i];
    shuffledNames[i] = shuffledNames[j];
    shuffledNames[j] = temp;
  }

  shuffledNames.forEach((shuffledName, index) => {
    shuffledName.id = index;
  });

  this.setState({ shuffledNames: shuffledNames });
};
```

This is my state before shuffling

[image: This is my state before shuffling]

This is my state after shuffling

[image: This is my state after shuffling]

Comment: No images of code, or object descriptors please. Enter the text and format it.

Comment: @trincot in the pictures that's not really my code, but it's chrome's react debugging

Comment: @pilchard It does answer, thank you.

Comment: I know. But Chrome's console is not an image. It presents text you can copy. Even better is to output the JSON representation and copy that text and format it.

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator is a shallow clone, so it's a new array but the same values which are object references, not new objects.  You need to find or code your own clone or deep copy function. Last one I used was randa's clone function but that was because someone else on my team had already imported that library.